# Problem with ASP.Net framwork 4.7. Return file. No download prompt

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Im making a controller that is to return a file based on a model in a database but im having issues with getting a prompt to download the file. The controller looks like this atm:

```
public ActionResult CreateFile(string ID) 
    {
        int id = int.Parse(licneseFileID);
        File_Type file = db.Files.FirstOrDefault(li => li.ID == id);
        string fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\TempData"), file.NAME.Replace(" ", string.Empty) + ".lic");
        
        WriteFile(fileName) //Here the file is created and its content is writen based on the data model

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(Server.MapPath(@"~\rlmsign12.exe"), fileName); 
        
        Process.Start(startInfo); //im runnig a 3rd party .exe to sign the file for licensing

        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Works?");
            return File(fileName, MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(fileName), System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName)); //The problem is here. Getting no download when it runs. filename is a full path.
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Fail");
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            //send file to blob here if we are going to be using a blob.
            //System.IO.File.Delete(fileName); //Delete file from application to avoid filling it upp with files. Send to local storage? Extra backup
        }
    }
```

To explain it.

Get the file from the database

Save it path to "fileName".

Run it through a method that creates the file in a sub folder in App_Data and then writes the files content.
Sign the file with 3rd party software.

Send the file to user. <-This is the problem.

Delete the file

So the problem is when i run the controller im getting no download prompt thorugh the client.
I know that the return statement does not fail since it does not throw an exception. Ive checked downloads and there is nothing.

I tried turning of chrome security.

Ive tried to return the file as a byte array. I have also tried some diffrent content types.

Am i missing something obvious like a attribute to the method?

The method is currently run directly by the index metod in the controller class (with hard coded argument) for testing purposes.

Edit:
IE it is called when the page is loaded.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CreateFile("2");
        return View(db.LICENSE_FILES.ToList());
    }
```

Comment from Peter B brought upp something pretty obvious. Im calling the method before the view even is returned. Legacy from when i was writing it.

Edit 2:
Tried calling the action with Jquery:

```
<script>
function call()
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: '/LicenseFiles/CreateFile',
        data: { licneseFileID: "2" }
    })
    .done(function ()
    {
        alert('test');
    })
}
```

I can se the action get called in the network tab but i am getting no prompt to save the file and nothing gets downloaded.

Comment: Check the network tab in the browser's console. Do you see the call there? If so, are there any errors?

Comment: What do you mean by `is currently run directly by the index met(h)od in the controller class`? Do you mean that `Index()` makes a direct method call to `CreateFile(someIndex)`? Please show that code if it exists, by [edit]ing the question.

Comment: What is the code that calls this? It's possible there's mismatch between the webrequest and response

Comment: Have edited the post with the call to the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 1st attempt (calling `CreateFile` from `Index`) isn't going to work, and it looks like you already understand why. Instead, doing a *redirect* to `CreateFile` would work, but then the file download will be the ultimate response of the call that was made to `Index`, and no new View will be shown.

The 2nd attempt doesn't work because a download only "happens" if the request was done by the browser window. When using `$.ajax` it's a `XMLHttpRequest` object that makes the request, it will receive the data and then it is up to you to extract the data and e.g. turn it into a Blob for download - not really easy or convenient.

A much easier solution would be to do this:

```
window.location = "/CreateFile/2";
```

or possibly (depending on your routing):

```
window.location = "/CreateFile?id=2";
```

Comment: Yeah the problem was only where and how i called the action. Thank you for your help.